# Error -25 when bitcoind sendrawtransaction

Tags: bitcoind, raw-transaction, rpc-error-25

I am trying to send a bitcoin raw transaction, but always got such an error. what's the possible explaination?

```
bitcoind --testnet sendrawtransaction 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
error: {"code":-25,"message":""}
```

The transaction looks like this when decoded:

```
{
    "txid" : "c6a8bb034ca48abe2618b6fb0f9f2c518370ee34bf88a5287be0de40a262e1b2",
    "version" : 1,
    "locktime" : 0,
    "vin" : [
        {
            "txid" : "71a063c7b0b6d0bae367043a6ce25205f9d5571f1f97b245515e7b25c7ee9bef",
            "vout" : 0,
            "scriptSig" : {
                "asm" : "3045022100e3c9147c6f801436a1880abd4b2c864fff9b405b3225ee7e274acf036515246a02207d3c816b1938954bb23b8d27a884777f871164f250f85e4fe67b3bc59d4903c101 029e324730c89a254f0d8b2b0d716325d6e7e35a045a30d602d576212453e92090",
                "hex" : "483045022100e3c9147c6f801436a1880abd4b2c864fff9b405b3225ee7e274acf036515246a02207d3c816b1938954bb23b8d27a884777f871164f250f85e4fe67b3bc59d4903c10121029e324730c89a254f0d8b2b0d716325d6e7e35a045a30d602d576212453e92090"
            },
            "sequence" : 4294967295
        },
        {
            "txid" : "4274f297a12c1e58ae7f878224e31b733fd817559cb3bf0f9ddbaf1aa1a15101",
            "vout" : 3,
            "scriptSig" : {
                "asm" : "3044022031dd44df55f376581cc7c51c9dad5784cabf799bc384cc895e48708332e7f15402204f4a23afed393409af596034cc78dc92fe7bc887ced4df70758c99e3def9bdc101 03bfefa3db6c30063e6df10262909e8841e72631e506bc4e674a1d5fd7ad9458b4",
                "hex" : "473044022031dd44df55f376581cc7c51c9dad5784cabf799bc384cc895e48708332e7f15402204f4a23afed393409af596034cc78dc92fe7bc887ced4df70758c99e3def9bdc1012103bfefa3db6c30063e6df10262909e8841e72631e506bc4e674a1d5fd7ad9458b4"
            },
            "sequence" : 4294967295
        }
    ],
    "vout" : [
        {
            "value" : 0.00010000,
            "n" : 0,
            "scriptPubKey" : {
                "asm" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 7d9c76fdb9889d0316ecea5fb6a49efd5bfb91a4 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "hex" : "76a9147d9c76fdb9889d0316ecea5fb6a49efd5bfb91a488ac",
                "reqSigs" : 1,
                "type" : "pubkeyhash",
                "addresses" : [
                    "mry8CQ4H8xnYEafH2awKhh6sXogu3DHoL1"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "value" : 0.00000000,
            "n" : 1,
            "scriptPubKey" : {
                "asm" : "OP_RETURN 4243500102dbee2551bb9f567934a35dfd12cc8a16cfe25476a366b14b26147bb17eaebe82",
                "hex" : "6a254243500102dbee2551bb9f567934a35dfd12cc8a16cfe25476a366b14b26147bb17eaebe82",
                "type" : "nulldata"
            }
        },
        {
            "value" : 0.00010000,
            "n" : 2,
            "scriptPubKey" : {
                "asm" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 a7373b9c82d4490450ae5fb18ef6e68b5f1ba414 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "hex" : "76a914a7373b9c82d4490450ae5fb18ef6e68b5f1ba41488ac",
                "reqSigs" : 1,
                "type" : "pubkeyhash",
                "addresses" : [
                    "mvm7JjdkMAqYt2b8VrJifnveHo3XWfLRBR"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "value" : 0.27969593,
            "n" : 3,
            "scriptPubKey" : {
                "asm" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 ccc6d502c38ec401a4203d0205adb49ea13e0794 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "hex" : "76a914ccc6d502c38ec401a4203d0205adb49ea13e079488ac",
                "reqSigs" : 1,
                "type" : "pubkeyhash",
                "addresses" : [
                    "mzBiLHKBSLNfJ1YHemSnBL2hf8MmuuV5Am"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my debug.log:

```
2014-12-28 15:58:21 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000105ce47aa2a182737da73cdc61f180bdbb2c8b7268ed2170  height=336335  log2_work=81.862093  tx=55205709  date=2014-12-28 15:55:21 progress=0.999995
2014-12-28 15:58:21 ProcessBlock: ACCEPTED
2014-12-28 15:58:35 connect() to 162.210.198.184:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2014-12-28 15:58:42 ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool : inputs already spent
2014-12-28 15:58:48 ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool : nonstandard transaction: dust
2014-12-28 15:58:48 ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool : nonstandard transaction: dust
2014-12-28 15:58:48 ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool : nonstandard transaction: dust
2014-12-28 15:58:48 connect() to 212.197.133.191:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2014-12-28 15:59:25 connect() to 60.240.240.47:8333 failed after select(): Connection refused (61)
2014-12-28 15:59:35 receive version message: /Satoshi:0.9.3/: version 70002, blocks=216962, us=129.31.191.110:64893, them=82.9.60.209:8333, peer=82.9.60.209:8333
2014-12-28 15:59:35 Added time data, samples 20, offset -4 (+0 minutes)
2014-12-28 16:10:17 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000011d9558507a7782247af10b62ebec6b56f27560b0f4b7a61  height=336336  log2_work=81.862149  tx=55206550  date=2014-12-28 16:10:18 progress=1.000000
2014-12-28 16:10:17 ProcessBlock: ACCEPTED
2014-12-28 16:10:28 ResendWalletTransactions()
2014-12-28 16:10:41 ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool : inputs already spent
2014-12-28 16:10:41 ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool : inputs already spent
2014-12-28 16:12:43 ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool : inputs already spent
2014-12-28 16:13:41 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001515448348af74726a44d0ab972ecc543444f506bd48dea0  height=336337  log2_work=81.862205  tx=55206582  date=2014-12-28 16:25:03 progress=1.000018
2014-12-28 16:13:41 ProcessBlock: ACCEPTED
2014-12-28 16:14:45 ERROR: AcceptToMemoryPool : inputs already spent
2014-12-28 16:16:50 Requesting shutdown
```

I am using bitcoind on a Mac, working on the testnet, so I am not sure if $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin/debug.log is appropriate to my situation.

Comment: Reading the source code, this error is returned when AcceptToMemoryPool fails, but not when it fails because the transaction is invalid. Does debug.log emit anything when this happens?

Comment: I can't seem to point out where this happens in debug.log. However, I can see two things that are likely explainations, added them to the question.

Comment: I think I have managed to work out that I accidentally made an attempt to double spend. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @fyquah95 the `-25 RPC error` will be more sophisticated for similar cases with the new `bitcoin-core` version: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/5418

Answer (score 3):

You get that obscure RPC error when your tx is using outputs that `bitcoind` never heard of.

For txs coming from the p2p network, there is an "orphan" mechanism, where `bitcoind` will wait for those missing outputs.

RPC txs are apparently expected to come in the right order.

As @GK pointed, a pull request is availbale at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/5418