# UPDATED: -25 when pushing multisig

Tags: json-rpc, multi-signature, rpc-error-25

I am trying to push this correctly signed 2/3 multisig to the network (based on [Gavin's example](https://gist.github.com/gavinandresen/3966071)) and I get  `RPC_VERIFY_ERROR = -25, //! General error during transaction or block submission`:

The requests and the responses to and from the console are:

```
{"method":"getnewaddress","params":[]}
{"result":"n3Cet7S4meopgzYdserFUpubMnXktqnzhL","error":null}

{"method":"getnewaddress","params":[]}
{"result":"my1NmQ5L6sYAZ8yLgEooQqzZ4QDJBMPjiL","error":null}

{"method":"getnewaddress","params":[]}
{"result":"mitERWMu8NiukHaGcMYJZnkCRJK6pzAd8P","error":null}

{"method":"walletpassphrase","params":["password",10]}
{"result":null,"error":null}

{"method":"validateaddress","params":["n3Cet7S4meopgzYdserFUpubMnXktqnzhL"]}
{"result":{"isvalid":true,"address":"n3Cet7S4meopgzYdserFUpubMnXktqnzhL","ismine":true,"isscript":false,"pubkey":"0316ac09be507f3d322cfdcbe328f7e03e720cd8c0ea4cd6dbd9b59e8d61d6f55c","iscompressed":true,"account":""},"error":null}

{"method":"validateaddress","params":["my1NmQ5L6sYAZ8yLgEooQqzZ4QDJBMPjiL"]}
{"result":{"isvalid":true,"address":"my1NmQ5L6sYAZ8yLgEooQqzZ4QDJBMPjiL","ismine":true,"isscript":false,"pubkey":"02910b3e90d39339dd765f971b03369f40c58f8b071d26c4de712daea3607d4d96","iscompressed":true,"account":""},"error":null}

{"method":"validateaddress","params":["mitERWMu8NiukHaGcMYJZnkCRJK6pzAd8P"]}
{"result":{"isvalid":true,"address":"mitERWMu8NiukHaGcMYJZnkCRJK6pzAd8P","ismine":true,"isscript":false,"pubkey":"024587719be74b5998bdc32239af62c99c62dba1eadff32e57b557ad61ae66f557","iscompressed":true,"account":""},"error":null}

{"method":"dumpprivkey","params":["n3Cet7S4meopgzYdserFUpubMnXktqnzhL"]}
{"result":"cPp5fVWM5oGbBtR41quKTqJbzUHfBz13RxjEJYRRmn1vszcmiJKc","error":null}

{"method":"dumpprivkey","params":["my1NmQ5L6sYAZ8yLgEooQqzZ4QDJBMPjiL"]}
{"result":"cQhdbAErfMzZYJMusn9usCKNBDf5RaGHNhBf6xsyHzT2XGjCbseQ","error":null}

{"method":"dumpprivkey","params":["mitERWMu8NiukHaGcMYJZnkCRJK6pzAd8P"]}
{"result":"cVFY5Fm3vyQJD6VmadkCrqFDE1x69dMTcmf65Wa3G7e5EJTz3A8n","error":null}

{"method":"createmultisig","params":[2,["0316ac09be507f3d322cfdcbe328f7e03e720cd8c0ea4cd6dbd9b59e8d61d6f55c","02910b3e90d39339dd765f971b03369f40c58f8b071d26c4de712daea3607d4d96","024587719be74b5998bdc32239af62c99c62dba1eadff32e57b557ad61ae66f557"]]}
{"result":{"address":"2N4tGQhXYZoxg68zYenfixMPmXxiycteQd1","redeemScript":"52210316ac09be507f3d322cfdcbe328f7e03e720cd8c0ea4cd6dbd9b59e8d61d6f55c2102910b3e90d39339dd765f971b03369f40c58f8b071d26c4de712daea3607d4d9621024587719be74b5998bdc32239af62c99c62dba1eadff32e57b557ad61ae66f55753ae"},"error":null}

{"method":"listunspent","params":[1,9999999,[]]}
{"result":[{"txid":"024adfd176cbafa3e2b8277c6320cc91c71928a1d93cf161fcbbbe21b552a021","vout":0,"address":"n3qdUsihCUUvhVxDGSa9dTys6FQyRYtra6","scriptPubKey":"76a914f4daf7429115209dde3dbf656e297f4822a7e86488ac","amount":0.30409597,"confirmations":333},{"txid":"2ae481097bfe598054d93e643ade015df4923eca01ef1c4248369d2f76676d29","vout":0,"address":"mgTNUvatqaoondmCKF2wrqmZp5nHfiZ41X","account":"","scriptPubKey":"76a9140a4aa70fa43aa653e932f9902c75bee703f7b6b388ac","amount":0.04900000,"confirmations":275},{"txid":"391ccc07ede180c00e11bb4a2facc0c762b2e021e96cc4ed4c5b267a2cb770d4","vout":1,"address":"muNqJMhpVEqpCBBkL3E8cP7MBFuEaYCLjB","scriptPubKey":"76a91498089826f83411d7e789adf88d2fb1732697b69d88ac","amount":0.09884210,"confirmations":333},{"txid":"69d42deda3513d73f70b5363090fcf81dd0443b1834309ea7ca5f58359344204","vout":0,"address":"mgTNUvatqaoondmCKF2wrqmZp5nHfiZ41X","account":"","scriptPubKey":"76a9140a4aa70fa43aa653e932f9902c75bee703f7b6b388ac","amount":3.24246444,"confirmations":274},{"txid":"afa0f809762154686c30cb984a340153e99a198fa5eb7abb300a90efdb9514dd","vout":0,"address":"mgTNUvatqaoondmCKF2wrqmZp5nHfiZ41X","account":"","scriptPubKey":"76a9140a4aa70fa43aa653e932f9902c75bee703f7b6b388ac","amount":0.01000000,"confirmations":275},{"txid":"cbb0939185826c02051ca82bb3696a24bf39a87109f341f7cbb58e2a9ace202e","vout":0,"address":"mtHpxHgBaazaQWrShuQKgFQTHjLyT23Jbs","scriptPubKey":"76a9148c1e19935b9c0b761850d1baff330392a062d0ff88ac","amount":0.00675471,"confirmations":356}],"error":null}

{"method":"createrawtransaction","params":[[{"txid":"024adfd176cbafa3e2b8277c6320cc91c71928a1d93cf161fcbbbe21b552a021","vout":0}],{"2N4tGQhXYZoxg68zYenfixMPmXxiycteQd1":0.30409597}]}
{"result":"010000000121a052b521bebbfc61f13cd9a12819c791cc20637c27b8e2a3afcb76d1df4a020000000000ffffffff017d03d0010000000017a9147faacb8d21673992204a50440b1321f662fa92ae8700000000","error":null}

{"method":"signrawtransaction","params":["010000000121a052b521bebbfc61f13cd9a12819c791cc20637c27b8e2a3afcb76d1df4a020000000000ffffffff017d03d0010000000017a9147faacb8d21673992204a50440b1321f662fa92ae8700000000",null,null,"ALL"]}
{"result":{"hex":"010000000121a052b521bebbfc61f13cd9a12819c791cc20637c27b8e2a3afcb76d1df4a02000000006a473044022067e51a61dc767166d10741f2ec5950eedfbbb84c5522c0db46f9809bbd91edf10220583f5e3ab5c312b8ebfb5dc5e76b11e4bdf037dd89f2447fe15c11298b2cdeed0121024c4e2909b43dac78086b040e43b161408a0e019b686f0b1754e839f2604b14f0ffffffff017d03d0010000000017a9147faacb8d21673992204a50440b1321f662fa92ae8700000000","complete":true},"error":null}

{"method":"decoderawtransaction","params":["010000000121a052b521bebbfc61f13cd9a12819c791cc20637c27b8e2a3afcb76d1df4a02000000006a473044022067e51a61dc767166d10741f2ec5950eedfbbb84c5522c0db46f9809bbd91edf10220583f5e3ab5c312b8ebfb5dc5e76b11e4bdf037dd89f2447fe15c11298b2cdeed0121024c4e2909b43dac78086b040e43b161408a0e019b686f0b1754e839f2604b14f0ffffffff017d03d0010000000017a9147faacb8d21673992204a50440b1321f662fa92ae8700000000"]}
{"result":{"txid":"65410ac69571208ec2e92603c235d9424f18778131006d34a5516783c88c7bd1","version":1,"locktime":0,"vin":[{"txid":"024adfd176cbafa3e2b8277c6320cc91c71928a1d93cf161fcbbbe21b552a021","vout":0,"scriptSig":{"asm":"3044022067e51a61dc767166d10741f2ec5950eedfbbb84c5522c0db46f9809bbd91edf10220583f5e3ab5c312b8ebfb5dc5e76b11e4bdf037dd89f2447fe15c11298b2cdeed01 024c4e2909b43dac78086b040e43b161408a0e019b686f0b1754e839f2604b14f0","hex":"473044022067e51a61dc767166d10741f2ec5950eedfbbb84c5522c0db46f9809bbd91edf10220583f5e3ab5c312b8ebfb5dc5e76b11e4bdf037dd89f2447fe15c11298b2cdeed0121024c4e2909b43dac78086b040e43b161408a0e019b686f0b1754e839f2604b14f0"},"sequence":4294967295}],"vout":[{"value":0.30409597,"n":0,"scriptPubKey":{"asm":"OP_HASH160 7faacb8d21673992204a50440b1321f662fa92ae OP_EQUAL","hex":"a9147faacb8d21673992204a50440b1321f662fa92ae87","reqSigs":1,"type":"scripthash","addresses":["2N4tGQhXYZoxg68zYenfixMPmXxiycteQd1"]}}]},"error":null}

{"method":"getnewaddress","params":[]}
{"result":"mhfP4ayuaUnwHvbhumWhVbhu3TEyjVSAA7","error":null}

{"method":"createrawtransaction","params":[[{"txid":"65410ac69571208ec2e92603c235d9424f18778131006d34a5516783c88c7bd1","vout":0}],{"mhfP4ayuaUnwHvbhumWhVbhu3TEyjVSAA7":0.2584815745}]}
{"result":"0100000001d17b8cc8836751a5346d00318177184f42d935c20326e9c28e207195c60a41650000000000ffffffff015d698a01000000001976a9141788411f512e2e7cfd311acb48f878991a2a9f1188ac00000000","error":null}

{"method":"signrawtransaction","params":["0100000001d17b8cc8836751a5346d00318177184f42d935c20326e9c28e207195c60a41650000000000ffffffff015d698a01000000001976a9141788411f512e2e7cfd311acb48f878991a2a9f1188ac00000000",[{"txid":"65410ac69571208ec2e92603c235d9424f18778131006d34a5516783c88c7bd1","vout":0,"scriptPubKey":"a9147faacb8d21673992204a50440b1321f662fa92ae87","redeemScript":"52210316ac09be507f3d322cfdcbe328f7e03e720cd8c0ea4cd6dbd9b59e8d61d6f55c2102910b3e90d39339dd765f971b03369f40c58f8b071d26c4de712daea3607d4d9621024587719be74b5998bdc32239af62c99c62dba1eadff32e57b557ad61ae66f55753ae"}],["cQhdbAErfMzZYJMusn9usCKNBDf5RaGHNhBf6xsyHzT2XGjCbseQ"],"ALL"]}
{"result":{"hex":"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","complete":false},"error":null}

{"method":"signrawtransaction","params":["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",[{"txid":"65410ac69571208ec2e92603c235d9424f18778131006d34a5516783c88c7bd1","vout":0,"scriptPubKey":"a9147faacb8d21673992204a50440b1321f662fa92ae87","redeemScript":"52210316ac09be507f3d322cfdcbe328f7e03e720cd8c0ea4cd6dbd9b59e8d61d6f55c2102910b3e90d39339dd765f971b03369f40c58f8b071d26c4de712daea3607d4d9621024587719be74b5998bdc32239af62c99c62dba1eadff32e57b557ad61ae66f55753ae"}],["cVFY5Fm3vyQJD6VmadkCrqFDE1x69dMTcmf65Wa3G7e5EJTz3A8n"],"ALL"]}
{"result":{"hex":"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","complete":true},"error":null}

{"method":"sendrawtransaction","params":["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",true]}
{"result":null,"error":{"code":-25,"message":""}}
```

Related:

- [Error -25 when bitcoind sendrawtransaction](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/34203/error-25-when-bitcoind-sendrawtransaction)
- [Receiving `error: {"code":-25,"message":""}` on sendrawtransaction with v0.9.3](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35484/receiving-error-code-25-message-on-sendrawtransaction-with-v0-9-3)

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you give a link to the UTXO you are trying to spend? I went to blockchain.info and searched for `e5404d712e7445e7af4050beb33e56d79c815422f6bebe3fce6245efcddab7db` but I got an error: **Sorry we could not find any blocks or transactions matching this hash**.

Comment: @StephenM347 correct, it's not on the blockchain, I am trying to replicate Gavin's example: https://gist.github.com/gavinandresen/3966071

Comment: In that example, gavin made two transactions (the second depending on the first), and showed that you can make the second transaction ahead of time and then send it out after the first one is published. Maybe you are sending them in the reverse order? Long story short, though, if the previous output isn't on the blockchain or in your mempool, then you can't really push a new transaction that depends on it onto the blockchain.

Comment: Can you include the raw hex of the transaction that this transaction depends on in your question?

Comment: @StephenM347 I have updated my question with a fresh example, ineluding the information you requested.

Comment: could you copy paste the commands you run?

Comment: @RubendeVries I have updated my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

afaik - 25 only happens if the output you're trying to use is already spent (either confirmed in the chain or by a TX in your mempool)

Comment: I take a random input from `listunspent` for the tx that pays the multisig. The test core doesn't create any other txs so it couldn't be spent. It couldn't be on the blockchain either since I never send it over. It's a very weird case.